# How to import FromString for joda-time?

Tags: scala, dependencies, jodatime

I try to use joda-time library for easier measuring the execution time of my program (not for profiling, just for the user).

But when I compile my project I get error about missing dependency -- the "FromString" class is missing. I tried to explicitly import it, but while typing intellisense (IntelliJ) does not even detect it, on the other hand there is only one jar for download from joda-time site.

**How do I resolve this dependency?**

*I am aware of wrapper for JT but for now I would like to use it directly.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the problem is with `FromString`, then the missing dependency is [Joda Convert](http://www.joda.org/joda-convert/). Add the relevant jars.

Comment: Thank you, you have supernatural powers obviously because Joda main site does not list this library :-) But you are right, thanks again.

Comment: This is utterly surprising that even after so ~4 years and so many versions of JDK and Scala later, the problem still seems to persist. Following @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala 's suggestion, the problem seems to have been resolved. Many thanks.

Answer (score 10):

This problem occurs because Scala doesn't implement annotations in the same way as Java. In Java, an annotation that is not found in the classpath is effectively ignored. Thus, loading Joda-Time classes in Java does NOT require [Joda-Convert](http://www.joda.org/joda-convert/). Since Scala does not load annotations in the same way as Java, Scala users are forced to add the dependency.