# Using Joda Time in Scala (scalaj-time) with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jodatime

**EDIT:**

Version information, as of 01/27/2013:

[Scala 2.10.0](http://www.scala-lang.org)
[IntelliJ IDEA Leda 123.139 (EAP)](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP)
[Scala Plugin version 0.7.108 (Nightly Build)](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+Nightly+Builds+for+Leda)
[JDK 7u11](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)
[Joda Time 2.1](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
[ScalaJ-Time 2.9.1-0.6](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalaj/scalaj-time_2.9.1)

I have given up on trying to work with **SBT**, as I didn't see any progress with it - I'm not sure how to combine **IntelliJ** and **SBT**, and after hours of trying, I had ended up where I'd first begun.

My JodaTime library contains the Scalaj-Time jar: [image]

I have tried almost every combination of settings, reaching from *Joint compilation (first Scala, then Java and vv)*, *external build*, over to *lifting my JodaTime library over Scala library in the dependencies* (yes, I've even done that), and *invalidating caches*. All I get is a bunch of errors - no matter if I "Make" the project, "Run" the current file or "Compile" it - that are produced randomly. And, sometimes, it works. Yes, as idiotic as it sounds, the behaviour is **that** undefined. I'm not sure as to what causes this. I have counted 3 different error messages that appear, I will upload them to pastie.org, otherwise it will take too much space: **http://pastie.org/pastes/5887847/text**.

What I have not tried: *Going back to earlier releases of any of the apps/libraries vide supra*, *getting deep into **SBT*** (I figured it's not worth it).

**What do I expect from this thread?** I expect that someone provide a solid solution to this problem which, in the best case, will not include any mention of **SBT** (optional).

Also, on a **side note**: Why does Joda-Time ship their library in a broken format? Is there any secret behind this that everyone should know about? What was the problem with including `FromString` into the release version? (I still think that's the cause of it all)

Regards,
Danyel

**ORIGINAL POST:** (you can ignore this)

I've got the latest build of IntelliJ (123.139), Scala 2.10.0, and hadn't encountered any problems thus far.

Instead of using Java time library, I was eager to use Joda Time, and seeing that there are a bunch of implicits to use in Scala, I wanted to try that out! I added all the libraries, but implicits wouldn't be recognized. When I tried to compile it via IDEA Popup Menu, following errors appeared:

```
error while loading DateTime, class file '~\workspace\Libraries\JodaTime\joda-time-2.1.jar(org/joda/time/DateTime.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/bad constant pool tag 10 at byte 42)
error while loading DateTimeZone, class file '~\workspace\Libraries\JodaTime\joda-time-2.1.jar(org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/bad constant pool tag 7 at byte 44)
error while loading AbstractInstant, class file '~\workspace\Libraries\JodaTime\joda-time-2.1.jar(org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/bad constant pool tag 10 at byte 10)
```

I went to the source of those `DateTime` and noticed that `org.joda.convert.FromString;` was imported, but the resource didn't exist! I guessed it was because of that why Scala wouldn't compile. So I googled for what I should do. And everywhere it said "SBT, SBT!!", and I was trying to find out what this SBT was, so I installed it: Version 0.12.2, Manual Installation (I'm using Windows 7) from http://www.scala-sbt.org/. I wanted it to run with my IntelliJ so I went to `~\.sbt\plugins`, and created a file `build.sbt` with the line `addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.2.0")` and downloaded the zip from https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea, extracted it, and went to that very folder with CMD, entered `sbt` and `gen-idea` within sbt and it did a lot of things and all seemed to work out. So I went to my project that I wanted to run Joda Time with, and first of all, it seemed very hard to include Scala 2.10.0 to SBT. I created a file `<PROJECT>\build.sbt` and filled it with these lines:

```
name := "Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaHome := Some(file("C:/Program Files (x86)/scala"))

scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
```

Then, to include the scalaj-time, I went to `<PROJECT>\project\project\` and created `build.sbt` with the line `libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-time" % "0.6"`.

Lastly, I went to <PROJECT> with CMD, entered "sbt", it (down)loaded a lot of files, and it seemed to work out, then I entered `gen-idea`, and everything was fine.

I opened IntelliJ and I could open the project easily. When I opened Project Structure, I went to Modules, and there were two Modules: `Project` and `Project-build`. I ignored the Project-build one, clicked on the Project module, and there were a lot of Source Folders and Test Folders that were not existent: `src/main/scala` etc., I removed them all and added my `src` as Source Folder.

I noticed that Joda-Time was not included in External libraries (btw I use Joda-Time 2.1 and Scalaj-time 0.6), so I had to add them myselves. The joda-time library is a .jar while the scalaj-time is a folder, but that should be no problem, right? I could run a simple `println( DateTime.now )` instruction (I don't know if it was possible before; didn't try), but a `+ 2.months` was still not possible. Here is a screenshot so you get the idea:

[image]

I think I explained in very detail how I proceeded and I hope that you can find something that I did wrong. I've been working for many hours to resolve this, but in the end, I landed where I was in the beginning...

Thank you for your time!

Regards!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8447353/38896

Comment: BTW, the Joda-Time isn't broken, the Joda-Convert dependency only involves an annotation which Java can handle if it is missing. Unfortunately Scala cannot handle the missing dependency, something which seems like a bug in Scala from my perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[How to import FromString for joda-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368529/how-to-import-fromstring-for-joda-time)**

This worked like a charm (for now, who knows how things will ensue). I am so mad that I didn't think of this in the first place... Grrrrr.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

This answer is invalid. See the EDIT in the main post. **While this works SOMETIMES, it is still heavily undefined as to WHEN it works. When I create a new project, it varies from working to not-working (not compiling, printing random errors), but in another larger project, it had the same undefined behaviour, except now (for whatever reason) it doesn't work, PERIOD. (On my newly created project it still varies)**

**ORIGINAL POST**:

So, after another 10 minutes of trying and googling, I found a .JAR for Scalaj-time (0.6).

I was like "Well, what harm can it bring?", downloaded it, and included it instead of the folder.

Tadaaa, everything worked... All I needed, too, was only these lines:

```
object Test extends App {
    import org.scala_tools.time.Imports._
    println( DateTime.now + 2.months )
}
```

No SBT, nothing, no other imports whatsoever. You just download scalaj_time from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalaj/scalaj-time_2.9.1 (Version 0.6, as of now) and Joda Time (V 2.1), make a library ScalajTime that includes 2+ jars, and add it to your dependencies. All you need is that one import statement and you are ready to go.

Maybe the main problem was that I cannot import SOURCE Files from libraries? Because the source folder I imported seemed to have no impact whatsoever. I don't know how I "ignored" that fact but it seemed stupid to assume.

So, now it works.

Regards.

Comment: Some comments: The behavior is sooo undefined. I keep getting error messages when I try to compile, and if I change some things in the settings it sometimes starts working. Right now I switched project, did the same thing, it didn't work there. I went to my other project (with provided source) and it didn't work there either! Like, what the hell? It had JUST compiled and run without problems and now it didn't work. I went to the settings, tweaked some stuff (first Javac, then Scalac, External) and so on, and after dozen of tries, it started working again. Anyone has any further info as to why?

Comment: I am entirely baffled. I went to my other project again and it didn't work, so I tried to configure some settings. It wouldn't work, somehow. I tried to "Compile" it and tried to "Run" it, but it just wouldn't work. So I **literally** clicked on "Run" thrice in a row, without doing ANYTHING in between. I just clicked on it, and it the first time there was a big list of errors, the second time there was "an uncaught exception" and the third time it worked. How is that even possible?... I have no idea what to believe anymore...